# Using a Jenkins pipeline to checkout multiple git repos into subdirectories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the Jenkins Multiple SCM plugin to check out two git repositories into two sub directories in my Jenkins job. I then execute one set of commands to build a single set of artifacts with information and code drawn from all three repositories.
But the branch test was checked out twice?
The workspace has current structure:

```
root
-.git
-all other files
-test
-res
```

I want that the workspace has this structure.

```
root
-test
-res
```

```
           node (label: 'YYY'){
     checkout([  
                $class: 'GitSCM', 
                branches: [[name: '*/test']], 
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'test']], 
                submoduleCfg: [], 
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'http://myrepo.git']]
            ])          
        
    dir('res') {
            git branch: 'master',  url: 'http://newrepo.git'
        }
    }
    
    pipeline {
        agent { label 'YYY' } 
        
        stages {
            xxx
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

U can clone multiple repos like this :

```
stage('Setup workspace') {
    dir('proj1') {
        git([url: 'git@gitlab.xxx.local:chenchuk/proj1.git', branch: 'master'])
    }
    dir('proj2') {
        git([url: 'git@gitlab.xxx.local:chenchuk/proj2.git', branch: 'master'])
    }
}
```

Although its not in the question, but it worth mention that it can be done in parallel also, like this:

```
stage('Setup workspace') {
    parallel('clone projects': {
        dir('proj1') {
            git([url: 'git@gitlab.xxx.local:chenchuk/proj1.git', branch: 'master'])}
    }, 'clone sf_tasks': {
        dir('proj2') {
            git([url: 'git@gitlab.xxx.local:chenchuk/proj2.git', branch: 'master'])}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function for this:

```
def checkoutGitRepo(final String repoUrl, final String repoBranch, final String folder) {
    //checkout in folder
    dir ("${folder}") {
        git(url: "${repoUrl}",
            credentialsId: 'jenkins-git-credential-id-here',
            branch: "${repoBranch}"
        )
    }
}
```

You can put that function in a shared library and call it in whatever build you need.

Comment: But why this above command do not checkout twice?, what is the problem of the code above?